# How to post another attribute instead of id in Input Token( jquery )

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I need some help regarding the Jquery Token input

http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

Basically i have a name attribute which i wanted to post instead of ID , Also i want the ability for user to enter a new tag if it doesn't present in the database.

That means the value of tags which will be posted is comma separated string of names and user can add a new one.

```
$(function() {
  $("#tags").tokenInput("/tags/?filter=1", {
    crossDomain: false,
    preventDuplicates: true,
    prePopulate: $("#tags").data("pre"),
    allowCreation : true,
    queryParam: "term"
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved an issue which is adding new tag using the things given in this url 
github.com/Mean-CJ/jquery-tokeninput/commit/… Which are

```
//$(this).val(""); //Adding these two lines 
 newToken = {'id':$(this).val(),'name':$(this).val()};
 add_token(newToken);
```

In the else part of case KEY.COMMA: In the js file